# In Spring MVC 4.1, is there any @NonResponseBody to return a normal view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4 `@RestController`, according to the spring doc, this is equivalent to `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`, so now **ALL** the methods in my controller return some JSON object.

But I just want to **exclude** one or two methods, I expect them to return a normal view. However, now spring will just send the literal string `admin/msg/msg_index` back to my browser.(see code blow)

How can I exclude these particular method, is there any `@NonResponseBody` annotation?

This is the configuration part.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="cnManager" />
<bean id="cnManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="false" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
    <property name="useJaf" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ViewResolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
</bean>
```

This is my controller.

```
@RestController
public class MsgController {

@Autowired
private MsgService msgService;

/**
 * RESTful method, list all msgs.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/msg", produces = { "application/json" }, method = GET)
public Result list() {
    try {
        List<Msg> msgs = msgService.findAll();
        return Result.ok(msgs);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return Result.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * View-based method, list all msgs.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/msg", method = GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    // Call RESTful method to avoid repeating lookup logic
    model.addAttribute("msgs", list().getData());

    // Return the view to use for rendering the response
    return "admin/msg/msg_index";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. Move your method to a different controller not annotated with `@RestController` or `@ResponseBody`.